# Updating row using Dynamic Data framework fails on some servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamic-data

One of our Dynamic Data applications exhibits a fault on a test server.

The use case is as follows: the user selects a row with a DateTime input field. The field template is enhanced with a JQuery calendar. The user enters som arbitrary but correctly formatted date. When clicking "Update" the application returns the following error:

```
Unable to convert input string '31.12.2011' to type 'System.DateTime'.
```

However, on our secondary test server and on my computer this works as expected.

The column has been configured like this in the data model:

```
    [UIHint("CalendarDateTime")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
    [DisplayName("Slutt")]
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
```

I am trying to find both a solution and an explanation. Can anyone help?

Thank you very much.

-Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points to consider :

What is CalendarDateTime? if this is a custom field template, check your code there.

Try adding this metadata : `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`

Try this dateformat string:  `DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]`

Consider using a DB data type **date**, instead of **datetime**, since that is the calendar data type.

Why is the date object stored in a string? Why not use `public object EndDate { get; set; }`